# How to print elements of a random list next to other elements in order?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, random, while-loop

Can anyone help me figure out how to print elements of a randomly created list next to chosen numbers in order?
The numbers are book names and the numbers that are random are book prices and I need those prices to be returned next to book names after you have chosen what books you are going to buy

Here is my code:

```
import random

print("Books for sale")

m = 25
price_list = []

for s in range(3, m + 1):
    price_list.append(s)

i = 0
books = 1
n = 10
book_list = []

while i < n:
  prices = random.sample(price_list, 1)
  print(f"{books}: {prices}")
  i += 1
  books += 1

print("Enter, which books are you going to buy (1 - 10) ==>")
numbers = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
print("Chosen books: ")

for el in range(len(numbers)):
    print(f'{numbers[el]}: {price_list.count(el)}')
```

It returns something like this:

```
Books for sale
1: [8]
2: [25]
3: [5]
4: [24]
5: [12]
6: [24]
7: [16]
8: [3]
9: [21]
10: [13]
Enter, which books are you going to buy (1 - 10) ==>

2 5 7
Chosen books: 
2: 0
5: 0
7: 0
```

I would like it to be more like:

```
Chosen books: 
2: 25
5: 12
7: 16
```

Comment: `print(a, b)` will print the values next to each other.

Comment: There are a couple of problems here.  When you get to the Chosen books loop, you want to look up the price that is associated with that book identifier.  list.count does not help you.  It gives you the number of times the el value appears in your price_list list, which not surprisingly is zero.  The way you have randomly assigned prices in the Books for sale loop means that when you get to the Chosen books loop you have no idea which price was assigned to which book.  Think about how you might associate the book id with the assigned price and you will be much closer to your solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the prices somewhere. A dictionary is a good container for this.

I also refractored a bit the code:

```
import random
print("Books for sale")
m = 25
price_list = list(range(3, m + 1))
n = 10
books = {}
for book in range(n):
  price = random.sample(price_list, 1)[0]
  print(f"{book}: {price}")
  books[book] = price
print("Enter, which books are you going to buy (1 - 10) ==>")
numbers = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
print("Chosen books: ")
for n in numbers:
    print(f'{n}: {books[n]}')
```

Output:

```
Books for sale
0: 5
1: 10
2: 18
3: 11
4: 20
5: 25
6: 13
7: 23
8: 8
9: 18
Enter, which books are you going to buy (1 - 10) ==>
2 5 7
Chosen books: 
2: 18
5: 25
7: 23
```